# App crashes when I click the search button in my other fragments

Tags: java, android, exception, crash, weather

My weather app works by searching cities on it's search panel and this works quite well. The only problem is that if i click the next tabs(hourly and daily section) on my bottom navigation view and
click the search button there, it shows the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.viz.lightweatherforecast.SecondFragment cannot be cast to com.viz.lightweatherforecast.FirstFragment
        at com.viz.lightweatherforecast.Activity.HomeActivity$2.onClick(HomeActivity.java:94)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7044)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7017)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:784)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26596)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6819)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:912)
```

This error clearly indicates that the error is from this line on the activity:

```
FirstFragment firstFragment = (FirstFragment) navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
                firstFragment.getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
```

So I tried adding this:

```
SecondFragment secondFragment = (SecondFragment) navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
                secondFragment.getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
```

So that it can support my secondfragment, but it still gave the error. I have as well searched this site for an answer, but haven't found any solution.

To explain the app further, I have an activity that hosts 3 fragments(Firstfragment, Secondfragment, and Thirdfragment. The 1st is labeled Today, 2nd is Hourly and 3rd is Daily for the weather.

I'm not planning on using the hourly and daily tabs for now until later versions of the app.
My other fragments are currently empty(no code written on them), I just want to stick to only the today tab for now.
But fixing this error is necessary, just in case of users click it.

My Aim is just to ensure that it doesn't give such an error if I click the search button on those other tabs, please help.

My Activity code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Last update time, click sound, search button, search panel.
    TextView time_field;
    MediaPlayer player;
    ImageView Search;
    EditText textfield;
    // For scheduling background image change(using constraint layout, start counting from dubai, down to statue of liberty.
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    public static int count=0;
    int[] drawable =new int[]{R.drawable.dubai,R.drawable.central_bank_of_nigeria,R.drawable.eiffel_tower,R.drawable.hong_kong,R.drawable.statue_of_liberty};
    Timer _t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        // use home activity layout.

        time_field = findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        Search = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        textfield = findViewById(R.id.textfield);
        //  find the id's of specific variables.

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        // host 3 fragments along with bottom navigation.
        final NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
        assert navHostFragment != null;
        final NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);


        // For scheduling background image change
        constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dubai);
        _t = new Timer();
        _t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // run on ui thread
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    if (count < drawable.length) {

                        constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(drawable[count]);
                        count = (count + 1) % drawable.length;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 5000, 5000);

        Search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // make click sound when search button is clicked.
                player = MediaPlayer.create(HomeActivity.this, R.raw.click);
                player.start();

                getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
                // make use of some fragment's data
                FirstFragment firstFragment = (FirstFragment) navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
                firstFragment.getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
            }

            private void getWeatherData(String name) {

                ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

                Call<Example> call = apiInterface.getWeatherData(name);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Example> call, @NonNull Response<Example> response) {

                        try {
                            assert response.body() != null;
                            time_field.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            time_field.setText("Last Updated:" + " " + response.body().getDt());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            time_field.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            time_field.setText("Last Updated: Unknown");
                            Log.e("TAG", "No City found");
                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "No City found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<Example> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }

                });
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Activity.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:background="@drawable/dubai"
    tools:context=".Activity.HomeActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="599dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textfield"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:autofillHints="@string/change_city"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:hint="@string/search_city"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:labelFor="@id/imageView4"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/searchbtn"
        android:src="@drawable/look"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/time_field"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textfield" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you should check the class of the fragment before castings it and also where is the search button located?. can you share xml layout?

Comment: After casting to `SecondFragment` instead of `FirstFragment` the error message can't be the same anymore. So, what is it now?

Comment: @plsankar the search button is located on the activity. I will share the XML layout now.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen I get the exact same error message as the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a correct reference to the displayed fragment from NavHostFragment you have to check the Fragment Class Type first before you try to downcast it.

Based on your question:

> App crashes when I click the search button in my other fragments

You cannot retrieve always the FirstFragment or SecondFragment instance as the visible Fragment when switching between other fragments.

So simply change your code to be like below:

```
Fragment currentFragment = (Fragment) navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
if(currentFragment instanceof FirstFragment) {
    FirstFragment firstFragment = (FirstFragment)currentFragment;
    firstFragment.getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
}
else if(currentFragment instanceof SecondFragment) {
    SecondFragment secondFragment = (SecondFragment)currentFragment;
    secondFragment.getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
}
else if(currentFragment instanceof ThirdFragment) {
    ThirdFragment thirdFragment = (ThirdFragment)currentFragment;
    thirdFragment.getWeatherData(textfield.getText().toString().trim());
}
```